# Preencher um ListView no Xamarin com dados

Tags: listview, xamarin

Bom dia. Estou tentando preencher um ListView em Xamarin com dados mas não estou conseguindo, fica dando uma exception genérica.

> ```
>         List<string> listaTeste = new List<string>();
>         listaTeste.Add("MIGUEL");
>         listaTeste.Add("RAFAEL");
> ```

```
        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Id.lvListaProdutos, listaTeste);

        lvListaProdutos.Adapter = adapter;
```

Alguém saberia me dizer se essa é a melhor forma de fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de realizar o carregamento de dados e exibição em uma ListView no Android.

Digamos que está que está tentando implementar, seria a mais simples, segue um código de exemplo deste modo.

```
    var Itens = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvListaProdutos);
    var valores = new List<string> { "Gol", "Celta", "Palio", "Fusca" };
    Itens.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, valores);
```

Veja os outras formas neste exemplo de código no github.

https://github.com/juniorporfirio/ListViewAndroidXamarin/blob/master/ListViewAndroid/ListViewSimpleExample.cs

Comment: Obrigado amigo, sua solução funcionou!

Comment: Olá Miguel apenas um toque. Eu sempre costumo dar um voto na resposta que resolveu, ou em outra que esteja certa, mas só podemos escolher uma. Votei nessa resposta, que poderá resolver a minha situação. Os caras são voluntários e voto sempre é um pontinho a mais pros caras, ainda que ninguém pede isso, é sempre legal votar. Apenas um toque e nada mais, cara. Valeu!!!